# Handling a CoreData save failures

Tags: swift, core-data

I am trying to better understand how to deal with a CoreData save failure when inserting a new row.

I can save new items into CoreData, there are all kinds of tutorials and references online to help with that. The issue I have is that in all of these tutorials they tend to gloss over the catch portion of what happens if my context.save() throws an error.

**What I see in tutorials online**

The the catch block just says "handle the errors" but I am trying to better understand how I should be handling this error.

```
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            //print there was an error or
            //Handle error here
        }
```

**My Contact NSManagedObject subclass**

I am using validateforInsert() to run my custom validation logic against the properties to ensure this is a good valid object before I save it to CoreData.

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Contact)
public class Contact: NSManagedObject {
    
    public override func validateForInsert() throws {
        try super.validateForInsert()
        try validateContact()
    }
    
    private func validateContact() throws {
        //validate this object to make sure its fields are set and the data is valid.
        
        guard let name = name, let email = email, let phoneNumber = phoneNumber else {
            throw(NSError(domain: "Error", code: 1)) //some important values were not set on this object, throw an error
        }
        
        if(name.isEmpty || email.isEmpty || phoneNumber.isEmpty) {
            throw(NSError(domain: "Error", code: 1)) //some important fields on this object are invalid, throw an error
        }
    }
}
```

**My current code**

This code works just fine and passes the validateContact() check if I supply all the correct fields. Below I have purposely commented out newContact.name property assignment so it will throw an error and fail to save. At first I didn't have the context.rollback() line in the catch block but it seemed like my invalid object was remaining in the context even though it failed to save because the next time I tried the same call validateForUpdate() would be called twice. So it seems like even my failed Contacts are remaining in my context as uncommitted changes so I need to get them out of there. After adding context.rollback() to the catch block this sorted everything out and all seems to be working fine.

Now I'm curious if this is the correct solution to my problem or not. Content.rollback() seems a bit aggressive to rollback ALL uncommitted changes especially when I still have a reference to the contact that failed to save, is there a way to remove just that one failed object from my context?

```
    private func saveNewContact() {
        guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else {
            showAlert(title: "Error", message: "There was an error saving your contact")
            return
        }
        
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        
        let newContact = Contact(context: context)
        //newContact.name = "John Smith"    //by not setting this name property we will fail our validation check and throw an error
        newContact.age = 20
        newContact.phoneNumber = "111-222-3333"
        newContact.email = "john.smith@gmail.com"
        
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            context.rollback() 
            showAlert(title: "Error", message: error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Comment: In this case I'd prefer an external validation **before** inserting the object because in practice inserting a new record on the main context with `init(context:)` and assigning the values with type safe dot notation will never fail.

Comment: @vadian
I have tried something to just make a contact object with Contact() then set the properties on it but i get this error. How would you recommend i make a new instance of Contact without inserting it into the context?

NSInvalidArgumentException - Reason [Contact setName:]: unrecognized selector sen to instance.

Comment: I mean do not perform the validation in `Contact` do it in `saveNewContact` before the `let context` line and return on failure. By the way `guard`ing `AppDelegate` is pointless. Force downcast the delegate. `AppDelegate` is required to be available otherwise the app won't even launch.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation and tutorials tend to be vague on that point because the best response depends on what the app is doing at the time. There's no one right answer. Some apps might do as you did, show an alert, and then maybe ask the user to fix the problem. Others might retry a network request, or throw away the invalid object, or do something else entirely, and that could be the right thing for their situation.

In your case, a likely scenario would be to prompt the user to fill in the missing name, and then save the complete record. That's a guess though, because I don't know the overall goal of the app.

Rolling back is a big hammer to throw at the problem, as you mention, but it can be the right one. Other options would be to fix the broken contact (maybe by asking the user), or to delete it from the context before saving.